# Unexpected output when multiple threads update same variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREAD (5)

int sum=0;
void* runner(void * param);

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREAD;i++){
    pthread_create(&tid[i],&attr,runner,NULL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREAD;i++){
    pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
            }
    printf("After threading %d",sum);
    return 0;
}


void * runner(void *param){
    for(int j = 0;j<10;j++)  sum+=j;    
    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

**output**: 225

In the following code, the output is 225. But the correct should be 45

I know threads share global variables!. so this function should correctly output right. But adding that sum=0 inside only gives correct output.  Whats happening here I don't understand!

```
void * runner(void *param){
sum=0;   // MY DOUBT 
for(int j = 0;j<10;j++)  sum+=j;    
    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

**output**: 45

Comment: `In the following code, the output is 225. But the correct should be 45` - You have 5 threads, each adds 45 (after all iterations) to `sum` variable. Total - 45 * 5 = 225. Why do you expect 45?

Comment: how does each add 45? also when i put sum=0 how can it change? help

Comment: You are using a single function for all your threads, you are not using mutex lock for the operation to complete, this is the reason you are getting unexpected output.

Comment: @curiousGuy: each adds 45 because in your `runner` function you have a `for` loop which calculates sum 0 + 1 + ... + 9 which is 45.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Thanks such a careless mistake. I thought of putting a sum+=1

Comment: You should **read a [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)** before coding any more. Also, compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: thank u so  much for that link @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [*data race*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-0619/geojs/index.html) because `sum` is accessed/modified by all threads without any synchronisation. So both 45 and 225 are "wrong". You may see different values in different runs. You need to [synchronize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Pthreads_synchronization) the access to `sum`.

Another thing to note you haven't initialized `attr` that you pass to `pthread_create`. You need to initialize it with `pthread_attr_init`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are dealing with is a race condition. With each systems, you'll get different output. The behavior of this code is not deterministic.
Because, as you create each thread, in a loop, `runner` function, which iterates for 10 times, is invoked in an order which can not be known.

So, expecting `45` or `245` or anything for that matter is wrong.

Race condition is an undesired condition when multiple threads can modify a common/shared data at the same time because they can have access to it. 
The scheduler which can behave differently from system to system might switch between those 5 threads at any point in time. To have a deterministic behavior, this needs to be addressed by some synchronization technique like Mutex or a Semaphore.

Mutex are my favorite for that. Not writing the whole code for you, because its not necessary with the question and I am lazy.

The rough steps to do the same would be:

Where you create threads,

- Initialize Mutex before you create threads
- Create threads (0 to n)
- Destroy Mutex once you are done
- pthread_join

And in thread handlers, in your case `runner` function,

- Lock Mutex
- Do something
- Unlock Mutex (Don't forget this!)

So, your `main` should contain [`pthread_mutex_init`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init), if it does return NULL, you can proceed.

In `runner` function, [`pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) should be the first trivial thing it does, followed by your code and then finally [`pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) before it returns.

The mutex you created can be destroyed by [`pthread_mutex_destroy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_destroy).

Its fun!

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying one global object from 5 threads. One thread increases value of `sum` by 45, so when you multiply it by 5 you have 225.

Another issue here is that you modify one variable from each thread which may end up in some mess caused by races.